# PyQt5 - QDate methods

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I was trying to convert QTime to string, so I decided to check the [reference guide](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/api/qdate.html).

Pretty helpful as you can see. Following the link to the C++ reference, I could find many methods that are no presented on QDate class, for example:

> File "qRobbieMain.py", line 29, in **init**
>       dateTest = self.dateEdit.date.addYears(1) AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'addYears'

What I'm doing wrong on this case?

Code:

```
self.dateEdit.setDate(QtCore.QDate.currentDate()) #setting date to current date
dateTest = self.dateEdit.date.addYears(1)
```

dateEdit came from the ui file convertion, which is pretty long, but basically the code is:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        self.dateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(self.frame)
        self.dateEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 160, 181, 23))
        self.dateEdit.setObjectName("dateEdit")
        (... more definitions...)
```

Comment: What is the class of your dateEdit ? It looks to me like you should do self.dateEdit.date().addYears(1)

Comment: Sry I forgot this, I will edit

Answer (score 0):

You forgot parentheses after `self.dateEdit.date`. This results in a function, not a `QDate` object. Try:

```
dateTest = self.dateEdit.date().addYears(1)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but why Visual Code can't show me this option when I type self.dateEdit.date().addYears(1). ?